# Alternative while loop without break

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, scanf

```c
    int number = 0;

   while (scanf("%d",&number)){

       if (sayi == 1 || sayi == 2){
           printf("Login succesful ");
           break;
       }


    }
```

How can I write this code without `break`?

Comment: What's wrong with `break` so that you don't want to use it?

Comment: I would like to evaluate another algorithm without continue/break.

Comment: The [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) family of function will return `EOF` on error. `EOF` is defined as a negative value (usually `-1`) which when used in a condition will be implicitly converted to "true". So if there's an error or the user presses the end-of-file keyboard combination, you will have an infinite loop. Do an explicit comparison of the returned value with `1`. As in `scanf(...) == 1`.

Comment: @Burakkepuc, that doesn't answer my question, there is nothing wrong with continue/break

Comment: maybe you can define a flag outside the loop and put it in the while condition.

Comment: You can use `goto`s. You can (ab-)use `&&` and `||` operators or ternary opreator and put the `printf` in the condition. Why would you want to use it?

Comment: You can use a `do..while` loop. You can use a `for` loop variant.

Comment: Why do you need the `if` inside the loop at all? Does `sayi` actually get changed inside the loop? If not just have it outside the loop and then the `while` in the body of the `else` case. Or is the `if` condition supposed to be checking `number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `break` is better here. It more closely hints at the more optimal assembly output.
But you can always use another variable (BTW, your error checking of `scanf` is wrong).

```
int number = 0;
_Bool not_broken=1;
while (not_broken){
   if (1!=scanf("%d",&number)) {/*handle error*/}

   if (number == 1 || number == 2){
       printf("Login succesful ");
       not_broken = 0;
   }
}
```

---

I'd recommend against trying to stuff everything into the `while` condition. It's less readable and even if a `scanf` failure ultimate results in a jump out of the loop (e.g., if you have `not_broken=0` in the `/*handle error*/` part), you'll still usually want to do something different in response to an error than in response to different inputted choices. The separate `if` is a cleaner way towards providing such separate responses.

(I have also taken the liberty to change `sayi` to `number` because using an unrelated variable there seemed like a coding error.)

Comment: Note that you logically used the variable `number` to check if whether it contains `1` or `2` or not, but in OP's code it is the mysterious `sayi`, which seems to has no relation to `number`.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Yes. I believed that to be an error. I've edited a mention of it into the answer. Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1):

You could use ternary operator inside while condition:

```
while (
       scanf("%d",&number) == 1 && 
       (sayi == 1 || sayi == 2) ? (printf("Login succesful"), 0) : 1
);
```

You could also chain `&&` `||` operators and use short-circuiting:

```
while (
       scanf("%d",&number) == 1 && 
       !( (sayi == 1 || sayi == 2) && (printf("Login succesful"), 1) )
);
```

Comment: That's tricky. Note [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62387458/alternative-while-loop-without-break/62387900#comment110338224_62387458). - Probably OP meant `number` instead of `sayi` but it still keeps a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` instruction is just a jump. You can use the `goto` statement instead. However, using `goto` is a **bad practice**. Your code looks good with the `break`. Anyways, that's how you'd write it with `goto`:

```c
int number; // removed assignment as it's unnecessary.

while (scanf("%d",&number)) {
    if (number == 1 || number == 2) { // I believe you meant number not sayhi.
        printf("Login succesful ");
        goto break_label;
    }
}

break_label:
// Put other work here, or return 0 if this is the end of the main.
```

Another way is using a flag variable as mentioned in the other answer by @PSkocik.

Answer (score 0):

For starters pay attention to that the condition in the while statement

```
while (scanf("%d",&number)){
```

can evaluate to true even when the call of `scanf` was not successful. So it will be correct at least to write

while (scanf("%d",&number) == 1){

As for the loop then here you are.

```
int number = 0;

while ( number != 1 && number != 2 && scanf("%d",&number) == 1 )
{
    if ( number == 1 || number == 2 ) printf("Login succesful ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: `sayi` seems to not get changed in the loop. So its checking would be better placed outside of it. Or did you just confused with `number` (which makes more sense). Please don't post post code which does not reflect your issue.

---

But just to dump another approach, assuming there is anything further that can change the variable `sayi` in the loop:

You also can use a `do while` loop with a flag variable:

```
int i = 1;

do {
       // Anything that changes sayi (related to variable number).

       if ( sayi == 1 || sayi == 2 ) {
           printf("Login successful. ");
           i = 0;
       }

} while ( i || (scanf("%d",&number) == 1 )
```

---

Side note:

- `while(scanf("%d",&number))` is dangerous/incorrect as if an input error is happening, the returned value will be the negative value of `EOF`, which would be evaluated to `true` and the loop goes on, despite the error. Use `scanf("%d",&number) == 1` as condition instead.